# Adding Classes to Wordpress Menu's via wp_nav_menu_items

Tags: php, css, wordpress, navigation

I am looking to add a class to the very last li of each ul. SO for example if i have:

```
<ul>
   <li></li>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I want to add a filter to make this:

```
 <ul>
   <li></li>
   <li class="last">
      <ul>
         <li></li>
         <li class="last"></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this with a php function? I've seen examples that successfully target the first ul li but don't go any deeper then this!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: does this help?
http://webknight-nz.blogspot.ca/2009/04/styling-first-and-last-list-items-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code to your functions.php

```
function add_first_and_last($output) {
  $output = preg_replace('/class="menu-item/', 'class="first-menu-item menu-item', $output, 1);
  $output = substr_replace($output, 'class="last-menu-item menu-item', strripos($output, 'class="menu-item'), strlen('class="menu-item'));
  return $output;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'add_first_and_last');
```

This forces the extra markup to be added to the class list for the respective elements, rather than having more than one ID for a tag.

I think there should be a more elegant solution though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Libin. I don't believe that this adds mark up for nested lists however. Can you confirm if this targets child ul's?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this question was posted, but I've been searching for an answer to the nested list items problem as well and could not find it anywhere (just solutions for one-level lists). So I came up with this, which seems to work but feels kinda clunky. But anyway, add this to your functions.php:

```
function add_last_item_class( $items ) {
  $ar_index = array();
  // loop through all the items and save the index of the last item belonging to a specific parent
  for ( $i = 1; $i <= count( $items ); $i++ ):
    $ar_index[$items[$i]->menu_item_parent] = $i;
  endfor;
  // loop through the saved indexes and add the class 'last' to each of them
  foreach( $ar_index as $last_index ):
    $items[$last_index]->classes[] = 'last';
  endforeach;
  return( $items );
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'add_last_item_class' );
```